Restoring deleted encrypted partition
I accidentally formatted the entire hard disk (quick format into NTFS).
It contains multiple partitions of different file system

ext4 encrypted with LUKS (whole partition encryption)
ext4 no encrypted
NTFS not encrypted

I restored the partition (ext4 no encrypted) & (NTFS not encrtpted) using testdisk, but it seems complicated restoring the encrypted partition which is the partition that contains important files.
I searched for LUKS using grep, and it shows many lines containing 'LUKS'.
Here is the first line:
9f175110 c5 df 3c de b8 a7 f1 cb 36 0a e9 e9 4c 55 4b 53 |..<.....6...LUKS|

grep output
I tried losetup then cryptsetup but the latter shows an error:
Device /dev/loop is not a valid LUKS device

the encrypted partition shows on Testdisk (it shows total size of partition, size of stored data, and partition label name):
Disk /dev/sdb - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>L Linux                    0  32 33 36844  28 48  591898624  
 D HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33 121601  57 56 1953521664 
 D HPFS - NTFS          36844  28 49 95606  24 34  944011264  


   
Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB Backup_SB, 303GB / 282 GiB

Selecting P(primary) for Linux partition didn't work.
Selecting L(logical) for Linux then Enter shows this: (but it didn't work)
Disk /dev/sdb - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63

     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 E extended LBA             0  32 32 36844 254 63  591912878
 5 L Linux                    0  32 33 36844  28 48  591898624 


 [  Quit  ] >[ Return ]  [ Write  ]  [Extd Part]

